# How to change default browser?

Tags: i3-window-manager

I use i3 via regolith on ubuntu.

I set the default browser to chromium in ubuntu, and yet the key combination still opens firefox.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of locations this can be done:

1. ~/.config/mimeapps.list

```
 x-scheme-handler/http=vivaldi-stable.desktop;firefox.desktop;
 x-scheme-handler/https=vivaldi-stable.desktop; firefox.desktop;
```

2. ~/.profile

```
     export BROWSER=/usr/bin/firefox
```

3. ~/.i3/config

```
bindsym $mod+F2 exec brave
```